# Car Class Python Program

Tags: python, python-3.6

Here is my code. I keep getting a Name Error as my result. How should I fix this problem?

**Car Class**

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, year, make, speed):
        self.__year_model = year
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0

    def set_year_model(self, year):
        self.__year_model = year

    def set_make(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.__speed = 0

    def get_year_model(self):
        return self.__year_model

    def get_make(self):
        return self.__make

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

    #methods
    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed +=5

    def brake(self):
        self.speed -=5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed
```

**Program**

```
import Lab9_prob2

def main():

    year = input('Enter the car year: ')
    make = input('Enter the car make: ')
    speed = 0

    #Accelerate 5 times
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed()) 

    #Brake 5 times
    mycar.brake()
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    my_car.brake() 
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    my_car.brake()
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())

#Call the main function
main()
```

Comment: why are you using leading double-underscores?

Comment: I don't know. That is how the underscores show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- You have not created an instance: `mycar = Car(year, make, speed)`
- You have renamed `mycar` to `my_car`: ie `my_car.brake()`
- The class attribute is called `self.__speed`, it is not called `self.speed`.(accelerate, brake and get_speed methods)

---

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, year, make, speed):
        self.__year_model = year
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0

    def set_year_model(self, year):
        self.__year_model = year

    def set_make(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.__speed = 0

    def get_year_model(self):
        return self.__year_model

    def get_make(self):
        return self.__make

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

    #methods
    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed +=5

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed -=5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

def main():

    year = input('Enter the car year: ')
    make = input('Enter the car make: ')
    speed = 0

    mycar = Car(year, make, speed)

    #Accelerate 5 times
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.accelerate()
    print('The current speed is: ', mycar.get_speed()) 

    #Brake 5 times
    mycar.brake()
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.brake()
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.brake()
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.brake() 
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())
    mycar.brake()
    print('The current speed after brake is: ', mycar.get_speed())

#Call the main function
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
def makeCarClass():
    def initialize(self, model, color, currSpeed, maxSpeed, mpg, currFuel, mileage):
        self["model"] = model 
        self["color"] = color
        self["currSpeed"] = currSpeed
        self["maxSpeed"] = maxSpeed
        self["mpg"] = mpg 
        self["currFuel"] = currFuel
        self["mileage"] = mileage
        return self

    def changeSpeed(self, amount):
        newSpeed = self["currSpeed"] + amount
        if newSpeed >= self["maxSpeed"]:
            self["currSpeed"] = self["maxSpeed"]
        elif newSpeed <=0:
            self["currSpeed"] = 0
        else:
            self["currSpeed"] = newSpeed

    def move(self, miles):
        fuelNeeded = miles/self["mpg"]
        currFuel = self["currFuel"]
        if currFuel <= fuelNeeded:
            self["currFuel"] = 0
            self["mileage"] = self["mileage"] + currFuel * self["mpg"]
            print("Warning: Your car has run out of fuel")

        else:
            self["currFuel"] = currFuel - fuelNeeded
            self["mileage"] = self["mileage"] + miles

    return {"initialize":initialize, "changeSpeed":changeSpeed, "move":move}


carClass = makeCarClass()

car1 = carClass["initialize"]({},"Ferrari", "yellow", 0, 200, 10, 40, 0)
car2 = carClass["initialize"]({},"Honda", "black", 0, 120, 30, 40, 0)
print(car1)
```

Answer (score 0):

class Car:

```
def __init__(self,year,make):
    self.__year_model=year
    self.__make=make
    self.__speed=0

def accelerate(self):
    self.__speed +=5

def brake(self):
    self.__speed -=5

def get_speed(self):
    return self.__speed
```

## new file

import car

def main():
    my_car = car.Car(2019,"Toyota")

```
for i in range(5):
    my_car.accelerate()
    print("Speed = ",my_car.get_speed())

for i in range(5):
    my_car.brake()
    print("Speed = ",my_car.get_speed())
```

main()

Comment: Could you please explain the answer you provided?

Comment: the first section of code you create the class. then you need to start a new python file and import your file. my file was called car. then you use a for loop to call speed and break 5 times each. hope that helps